# Windows 10: Is it possible to control the display scaling (typically a monitor based setting) specific to a window?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings, scaling

I've got some PC displays with wildly varying DPI's. I have a typical 27" 2560x1440 which is 107 PPI and I have hooked up a 324 PPI iPad3 (sub 10", 2048x1536) screen converted to displayport with an Adafruit Qualia kit.

Windows 10 finally supports a seamless ability to scale up the display. So this high density display is finally "usable" since at 200% upscaling and at a distance where it far, far exceeds retina resolution, I can read text on it comfortably.

Indeed I also have a 65" 4K TV that I connect. This is 67 PPI. So there is a theoretical situation where I could upscale my 27" screen.

This is great but I was thinking it would be fantastic if I could mark certain windows as unaffected by the 200% scaling so that I can read them if I really squint but otherwise take up a smaller amount of real estate. You know I would put some task manager graphs and various hardware monitoring graphs and that sort of stuff.